# I am getting more than 50 auto layout constraint errors in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, autolayout, size-classes

When I closed Xcode last night, I had no constraint errors and when I opened Xcode today, it showed me 58 constraint errors. The number of constraint errors increased and decreased till they came down to 33. I have experienced this in the past also. When I wanted to fix this issue in the past, I would simply uncheck Auto Layout and check it again and the errors would disappear. But unfortunately, I cannot do that now as size classes has to be disabled then and that messes up my entire application.

Answer (score 1):

I started working on my iPad project with 
[image]

Next time when i opened my xcode project it had changed to 
[image]

and thus it showed too many constraint errors. I again changed it to 
Regular width and height 
[image]

and the errors disappeared. Check if your case is the same as mine.

Comment: That is not the problem here. It has remained Any|Any

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question because I found the solution :) I had a UIVisualEffect in my app. I just moved it to the back, and then back to the front, and the errors disappeared. Xcode does work in mysterious ways...

Answer (score -1):

You said

> I would simply uncheck Auto Layout and check it again and the errors would disappear.

I think disabling it will remove all the constraints, that's why the errors would disappear. It doesn't really solve any problem.

A general rule for setting up constraints is to go from general to specific.

In my last application, I first set all the common constraints in `Any Width | Any Height` and then set constraints that are specific to landscape iPhone in `Any Width | Compact Height`. Then I set the constraints that are specific to iPad and portrait iPhone in `Any Width | Regular Height`

Setting  constraints are indeed a painful thing to do, but they are worth it. Good Luck.

Comment: I uncheck it and check it again, so the constraints come back. These errors used to come even when size classes was not enabled.